# Computing Probability Using Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

$X_1,X_2...X_{100}$ are IID random variables with variance equal to 1. The mean of the random variables is not known. We estimate the mean by taking the sample average $\hat{\mu}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{100} X_i}{100} $. Use the central limit theorem to find the probability that the estimated mean and the true mean differ by less than $0.2$.

My solution:
Need to find 
$P(-0.2<\hat{\mu}-\mu<0.2)$
which is equivalent to finding:
$P(\frac{-0.2}{1/\sqrt(100)}<\frac{\hat{\mu}-\mu}{1\sqrt(100}<\frac{0.2}{1/\sqrt(100)})$
By Central Limit the expression in the middle of the inequality is approximately standard normal.
Thus the Probability is just
$\phi(2)-\phi(-2)\approx0.95$.  Is this correct? 
I'm not sure.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, the percentage of values within $2$ Standard Deviations is not exactly $95%$ (it’s closer to $95.45%$), but otherwise it’s correct.

Comment: @Kyky Thanks, I didn't know how to do the approximately equals to symbol in Latex

Comment: In LaTeX `\approx` gives $\approx$

Comment: @Henry Thanks I will edit

Comment: It has been edited